# Using IF statement to pull boolean column header for an entry

Tags: sql, if-statement, boolean

I'm not good at all with IF statements. I currently have a schedule that looks like this:

```
Lot(Int) PartNum(Varchar50) Amount(Int) IsPainted(Bool) IsInspected(Bool) Finished(Bool)
1         xxx-0191          500          1               1                 0
2         xxx-0191          700          1               0                 0
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, and I'm under the thought it'll have to be handled by an IF statement but I'm certainly open for using whatever works best here, is to have a query that will give me the following

```
Lot  PartNum  Amount  Status
1    xxx-0191 500     Inspected
2    xxx-0191 700     Painted
```

What I need it to do is just pull the last available column of "True" or "1" in the boolean columns and just display that information in the "Status" column in the query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
select 
    Lot, 
    PartNum, 
    Aamount, 
    Case when IsInspected=1 then 'Inspected' else 'Painted' end Status
from
    table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `case`.  Something like this:

```
select lot, partnum, amount,
       (case when Finished = 1 then 'Finished' 
             when IsInspected = 1 then 'Inspected'
             when IsPainted  = 1 then 'Painted' 
       ) as status
```

This chooses the last boolean as the one chosen for the status.

Comment: I had to tailor to add in "=1" for it to work, is that correct or did I miss something in this one? I appreciate the help greatly!

Comment: @DaveHolt . . . That depends on the database you are using.  You didn't specify the database and explicitly said the columns are boolean.  Even database that supports a boolean type accepts the type in a `when` clause.